# In Ionic app scrolling is not smooth for iOS 10, but it is in iOS 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ionic-framework

In the Ionic app with jQuery scrolling, I have been appending new DOM elements while scrolling the content, it has worked smoothly until iOS 9.3.

When I update my iOS to >9.3, scrolling is not working while touch move but it updates the content while I stopped the touch move.